# Pass a blank password to wbadmin (windows backup) via command line/batch file

Tags: batch-file, passwords

I have a Windows 2008 R2 server and need to execute the windows backup via a batch file on a scheduled task. The issue I have is the backup destination is a unix share drive with a username but no password (I dont have the option of adding a password as its outside of my control). Because there is no password the script stops waiting for a password to be entered when its set as a scheduled task. I might add, this script works absolutely fine if I run it manually, oddly without having to even press enter to put a blank password in.

My question: Is it feasible when the batch file is executed by the task that it can also presses/passes "enter" as if it was answering the command when it comes back "Input password"

Here's the code - I've removed the destination path and username for security. Its a UNC path.

wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:DESTINATION -allCritical -include:c: -vssFull -user:USER -quiet

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

You could try this:

```
echo. | wbadmin start backup -backuptarget:DESTINATION -allCritical -include:c: -vssFull -user:USER -quiet
```

It will pipe an "enter" into wbadmin.

EDIT:
Changed `echo` to `echo.`, only echo would print "echo is ON/off"

Comment: Thank you for the comments, I tried the first one and it didnt work. I will try the "echo." tonight during maintenance hours and post back.

Comment: Sadly it didnt work. It states in the piped log file - Retrieving volume information...
This will back up volume System (300.00 MB),Windows(C:) to DESTINATION.
Do you want to start the backup operation?
[Y] Yes [N] No Y

Provide a user name and a password for a user who has write permission to the
remote shared folder.

Comment: Sounds like you need to press "Y" first, do you? Try `echo Y | ...` In general you need to figure out which input is required in order to start the intended operation. Something like "y, return, return, username, return, password, return". Then you/we can build the required `echo` statement.

Comment: Sadly this was never resolved - I believe it is simply a limitation of the builtin backup software